# Updated information is not reflecting in mysql databse

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-data-jpa

I have setup a project by referring this blog but instead of using maven I have used gradle.
[Registration and Login Example with Spring Security, Spring Data JPA, Spring Boot](https://hellokoding.com/registration-and-login-example-with-spring-security-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-hsql-jsp/)

Everything works fine except updating value in Mysql database is not working.

I have created a request mapper to update user information.I have checked that request body is not empty and has all the values. Also I am getting response status as "SUCCESS". But when i see in Mysql database nothing seems updated. My request mapper is as follows.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateRegistration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, Object> updateRegiatration(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> requestBody) {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        UUID userId = UUID.fromString((String) requestBody.get("userId"));
        if (userId != null) {
            User user = userRepository.findOne(userId);
            user.setFullName((String) requestBody.get("fullName"));
            user.setPostOrDesignation((String) requestBody.get("designation"));
            user.setCurrentComapny((String) requestBody.get("companyName"));
            user.setState((String) requestBody.get("state"));
            user.setCity((String) requestBody.get("city"));
            user.setShortInfo((String) requestBody.get("shortInfo"));
            user.setEmail((String) requestBody.get("email"));
            user.setAddress((String) requestBody.get("address"));
            userRepository.save(user);
            response.put("STATUS", "SUCCESS");
            response.put("STATUS_MESSAGE", "Successfully updated Information.");
        } else {
            response.put("STATUS", "ERROR");
            response.put("STATUS_MESSAGE", "Something went wrong while updating information.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

As I am new to java and spring, I am unable to figure out what is happening here. 
I have doubt that it is because of the 'hsqldb' used in the application. 
here is build.gradle file.

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-   plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE")
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37'
    }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

    jar {
        baseName = 'gs-accessing-data-mysql'
        version =  '0.1.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    dependencies {

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    // JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...)
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

    // Use MySQL Connector-J
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    runtime 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.1'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.0-beta9'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.0-beta9'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
    compile("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper")

    compile('javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api:1.2.1') {
        transitive = false
    }
    compile('org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:1.2.1') {
        transitive = false
    }
}
```

Also i have set application.properties file as follows

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=abc123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Comment: could you comment out the runtime 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.1' in you gradle ?

Comment: @georgesvan When i commented this... i get error as "Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE
"

Comment: actually, mysql whas not reflecting your cruds simply because it was persisted in hsqldb  embedded databse.  Now your app throws an exception because it is not able to locate your application.properties.

Comment: add runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java') in your gradle and try.

Comment: @georgesvan not working, getting same error when used runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java'), Actually when I register for the first time, the values get stored in mysql database. But its not working when i try to update.

Answer (score 0):

In general you need a transactional service layer.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyService {
}
```

So in short:

- Declare repositories
- Declare transactional services that use those repositories
- Use your services inside your controllers

Just to make your code work in a quick-and-dirty way, try annotating your `updateRegiatration` method with `@Transactional`:

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateRegistration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, Object> updateRegiatration(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> requestBody) {
}
```

Anyway, if you look at the example code, you see this service layer:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        for (Role role : user.getRoles()){
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

And the controllers use services, not repositories:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;
```